# Async image file save

Tags: c#, asynchronous

In a web mvc project.

I have the following function I am trying to make async as I save many files and its a bit slow. Do I need to add to a list of tasks and await all:

```
   var fs = new FileSaver();
        property.FloorPlanPath = fs.SaveFile(propertyRentalForm.FloorPlanFile, "~/uploads/properties/floorplans");
        property.FloorPlan2Path = fs.SaveFile(propertyRentalForm.FloorPlan2File, "~/uploads/properties/floorplans");
        property.EpcPath = fs.SaveFile(propertyRentalForm.EpcFile, "~/uploads/properties/epc");

    public string SaveFile(HttpPostedFileBase file, string uploadPath)
    {

        if (file == null || file.ContentLength <= 0) return "";
        var fileName1 = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        if (fileName1 == null) return "";
        // clean file name
        fileName1 = string.Format("{0}{1}",
            Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName1).GetAliasTitle(),
            Path.GetExtension(fileName1));

        var path = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(uploadPath), fileName1);
        file.SaveAs(path);
        return fileName1;
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you just use a `BackgroundWorker`?

Comment: you got code example, this is a mvc app

Comment: is this the best option though or async and await

Comment: I would use a `BackgroundWorker`.  Why don't you read about it and decide for yourself?

Comment: @LukePark Why would you use a `BackgroundWorker` in a web context?

Comment: exactly my point thought for console or wpf apps

Comment: @CharlesMager Apologies, didn't bother reading the code since the question was so generic and wasn't tagged.

Comment: Quick reminder: async is NOT parallel.

Comment: Use async calls to prevent blocking/freezing within your application.  Async will not increase the speed at which your computer can write data to the disk.

Answer (score 0):

If you have single disk to save those files there is no meaning to make it async. Because you have limited by your disk I/O. But you can use a queue mechanism and you can check this queue status asynchronously...

Comment: so there is no advantage to:     var tasks = new List<Task<string>>
            {
                Task.Run(() => fs.SaveFile(propertyRentalForm.FloorPlanFile, "~/uploads/properties/floorplans")),
                Task.Run(() => fs.SaveFile(propertyRentalForm.FloorPlanFile, "~/uploads/properties/floorplans")),
                Task.Run(() => fs.SaveFile(propertyRentalForm.FloorPlanFile, "~/uploads/properties/floorplans"))
            };

            var results = Task.WhenAll(tasks);

Comment: If you have one physical hard disk drive to save those files, yes there is no meaning. But you can create those tasks on server side in a `ConcurrentDictionary<string, Task>` (Don't forget to remove finished tasks) (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx) and you can check their statuses. May be you want to check Singleton design pattern or `Lazy<T>` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx). Also another option is `Threadpool` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as.aspx).

Comment: Also don't try to save those files directly, first create `MemoryStream` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream(v=vs.110).aspx) to save those files in memory after then queue them in some queue mechanism using methods which i mentioned...